# CSS webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio - how to prevent images from scaling up and becoming blury?

Tags: html, css

I encountered a problem of images in a website I am developing getting scaled up the window's scale and layout is set to 125%.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.00), (min-resolution: 100dpi) {
    body {
    background-color: midnightblue;
  }
}
    
    
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    body {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
  }
}
```

This code works to detect it, ie. is set to 100% the BG is midnightblue, if to 125% then darkslategrey. I could just try down-scaling ALL images if this 1.25 ratio is detected, but probably that's not an effective thing to do. So is there a way just to turn the upscaling off?

Thanks )

Answer (score 0):

seems I found a kinda working solution:

```
 @media screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) { 
     body { transform: scale(0.8) }
}
```